# Get last inserted id Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and I'm trying to get the last inserted ID in raw query.

My query is

```
.query(Sequelize.Utils.format(["insert into MyTable (field1, field2) values (?,?)", val1, val2])
```

The query is done perfectly, but the result on success event is *null*.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

---

After some researches and zillions attempts, I understood how callee object work in sequelizeJs.

please, correct me if my answer is wrong.

the callee object needs this structure

```
{__factory:{autoIncrementField: 'parameterName'}, parameterName: '' }
```

in this case "parameterName" is the field that will store the new ID, sequelize looks for  __factory.autoIncrementField to set value of last inserted id into property with its value (value of __factory.autoIncrementField).

so, my call to querys method would be

```
.query(sequelize.Utils.format(tempInsert), {__factory:{autoIncrementField: 'parameterName'}, parameterName: '' }, {raw: true})
```

this will result in object like that

```
{ __factory: { autoIncrementField: 'parameterName' }, parameterName: newInserted_ID }
```

thanks for all, and I hope this can help someone.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I've come across the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes your answer is working. Another way would be

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize")
var sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'root', {dialect: 'mysql'})

var Page = sequelize.define( 'page', {
  type  : {type: Sequelize.STRING(20)},
  order : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, defaultValue: 1}
},{
  timestamps: false,
  underscored: true
})

Page.__factory = {autoIncrementField: 'id'}
Page.id = ''

sequelize.query('INSERT INTO pages SET `type` = ?, `order` = ?, `topic_version_id` = ?', Page, {raw: false}, ['TEXT', 1, 1] ).success(function(page) {
  console.log(page)
  Page.find(page.id)
    .success(function(result){
      console.log(result)
    })

})
```

Comment: I'm curious, you're setting `raw: false`, but your query is a raw query. Am I missing the purpose of the `raw` property? Could you explain why you did this?

Comment: so far i remember, `raw: true` will not map result into model.

Comment: Just getting into Sequeulize. I defined my model with a column:

``` id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true }```

Yet the only way I get back the inserted ID is with your method above. This seems strange? Is there a reason this isn't documented anywhere else?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that now, I am able to get `id` after `save` or `create` when `id` field is defined as `id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true}`. The key part is `autoIncrement`, if you remove it you won't get back `id`.

Answer (score 25):

You have to add **autoIncrement property** in model definition.

```
const Article = sequelize.define('articles', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  }, {},
  {
   createdAt: false,
   updatedAt: false
  });
```

Then, you can access last inserted id with property in model definition.

```
Article.create(article)
  .then(result => console.log(result.id));
```

Comment: I was missing this. I thought Sequelize will automatically consider primary key as auto increment column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const addAuthUser = await authModel.create(
      { 
          username: username, 
          password: hashedPassword
      });
  if (!addAuthUser) {
      return next(new HttpError('SignUp Failed!', 401));
  }
// this last inser id
  console.log(addAuthUser.id)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.