# Get last inserted id from Sequelize.js "query" (MySQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize in one of my projects and am having some trouble with a custom non-model query.

For example:

```
var query = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ("Bob");";
sqlCon.query(query)
    .on('success', function(result) {
        console.log(result); // No inserted record or last insert id
    });
```

I would like to have the inserted record returned to me in this case or at least the record id. Am I missing something to make sure "result" gets populated?

Comment: Is the success callback firing? does console.log display anything?

Comment: try `sqlCon.query(query).success(function(result) { ....`

Comment: @levi yes, the success callback is firing. If I put a basic string like "I'm running" it will echo it out.

Comment: A similar question and answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723507/get-last-inserted-id-sequelize

Comment: Is there no way to return the last insertion id for raw sql where you have no models?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('testa', 'testa', 'testa', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    flags: '-FOUND_ROWS'
  }
});
```