# How to insert an item into a sequence using Sequelize, or How to manage an ordering attribute

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an entity with a sequence attribute, which is an integer from 1-N for N members of the list. They are polyline points.
I want to be able to insert into the list at a given sequence point, and increment all the items at that point or beyond in the sequence to make room for the new item, and likewise if I delete then decrement everything above so we still have nice sequence ordering with no missing numbers.
There is a REST interface in this of course, but I dont want to hack about with that, I just want sequelize to magically manage this sequence number. 
I am assuming I need to get hold of some "before insert" and "after delete" hooks in sequelize and issue some SQL to make this happen. Is that assumption correct or is there some cooler way of doing it.

Comment: How about `INSERT INTO ... SELECT IDENTITY(1,1),..`

Comment: well IDENTITY does look like exactly the find of functionality I want, alas it's only SQL server.  But I'm still holding out that there's a thing in, or addable to, sequelize to do this, thanks.

Comment: Well, I think, when you insert, you can select lasted id as `last_id`, then insert `last_id + 1`
[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723507/get-last-inserted-id-sequelize)

Comment: On looking at IDENTITY on sql server, iit doesnt actually manage the column properly, it doesnt manage the insert or deletions properly anyway, so it's not what I want. It's not a problem to add one on the end, but this is a mapping app, you need to be able to edit paths, that means adding a new point in the middle. I'll add it as an attribute functionality to sequelize, I just wanted to check i wasnt doing something publicly available already.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but this appears to be the solution, which is barely worth comment.

I know the modelName, and name==the attribute name,

```
    options.hooks={
            beforeInsert: function(record, options) {
                return self.models[modelName].incrementAfter(name,record[name]);
            },
            afterDelete: function(record, options) {
                return self.models[modelName].decrementAfter(name,record[name]);
            }
        }
```

and then added to my extended model prototype I have

```
incrementAfter:function(field,position){
    return this.sequelize.query("UPDATE "+this.tableName+" SET "+field+" = "+field+"+1 WHERE "+field +" >= "+position);
},

decrementAfter:function(field,position){
    return this.sequelize.query("UPDATE "+this.tableName+" SET "+field+" = "+field+"-1 WHERE "+field +" >= "+position);
},
```