# Sequelize bulkCreate returns generated IDs or not with MySQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I read the [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate) it makes me think the generated IDs cannot be returned from a call to `bulkCreate`. Even the `returning` option parameter says it's a Postgres-only feature. This is also referenced in [this Sequelize issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5466#issuecomment-186855519).

But I ran the code below, with Sequelize v5.21.3 and MySQL 5.6.49, and it seems to work just fine (note that **I'm not even passing** the `returning: true` option.)

```
const MyEntity = sequelize.define(
  "MyEntity",
  {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "my_entity"
  }
);
await MyEntity.sync();

const saved = await MyEntity.bulkCreate([
  { name: "test1" },
  { name: "test2" },
  { name: "test3" }
]);
console.log(`*** SAVED:\n ${JSON.stringify(saved, null, 2)}`);
```

And it seems to correctly return the id's, printing this:

```
*** SAVED:
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "test3",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-29T14:04:27.127Z"
  }
]
```

So what's the truth? Can I trust that returning the id's will work regardless of how many records I'm trying top insert? Is this part of the documentation wrong or poorly phrased?

> The success handler is passed an array of instances, but please notice that these may not completely represent the state of the rows in the DB. This is because MySQL and SQLite do not make it easy to obtain back automatically generated IDs and other default values in a way that can be mapped to multiple records. To obtain Instances for the newly created values, you will need to query for them again.

Comment: Something is amiss because the size of the `id` column in your definition is smaller than the integers in your example output. You also don't need to define `id`, `createdAt`, or `updatedAt`, Sequelize will do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks @doublesharp. I don't know what's up with that (it's code from an inherited project, with things renamed to not reveal it). The entities were declared with Sequelize but the database schema is created and maintained using a different tool, like _Liquibase_. Usually the tables are created manually to match the Sequelize definition (error prone) and the Liquibase migration scripts are generated from the DB schema. There's room for improvement but that's a story for another day :)

Comment: That makes sense. What do you have set for the dialect? Are you sure the database is empty before you do the insert? What version of sequelize? The latest has this in `bulkInsert` - `['mysql', 'mariadb', 'sqlite'].includes(dialect)) {
                // The query.js for these DBs is blind, it autoincrements the
                // primarykey value, even if it was set manually. Also, it can
                // return more results than instances, bug?.
                continue;`

Comment: This answer indicates that if you *do* explicitly define the primary key with `autoIncrement` then it will return the ID, though i'm not sure why.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44646856/1427161

Comment: I found the answer in the Sequelize code, they fake it a bit. I'll post it in an answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sequelize code has some workarounds for MariaDB not returning the ID with inserts by assuming they will be created sequentially, there is a comment that says

> `//ONLY TRUE IF @auto_increment_increment is set to 1 !!`

As a side note it's interesting that's not configurable and hard coded to increment by 1...

***`./sequelize/lib/dialects/mariadb/query.js`***

```
  formatResults(data) {
    let result = this.instance;

    // update and upsert code....

    if (this.isInsertQuery(data)) {

      this.handleInsertQuery(data);

      if (!this.instance) {
        // handle bulkCreate AI primary key
        if (this.model
          && this.model.autoIncrementAttribute
          && this.model.autoIncrementAttribute === this.model.primaryKeyAttribute
          && this.model.rawAttributes[this.model.primaryKeyAttribute]
        ) {
          //ONLY TRUE IF @auto_increment_increment is set to 1 !!
          //Doesn't work with GALERA => each node will reserve increment (x for first server, x+1 for next node ...
          const startId = data[this.getInsertIdField()];
          result = new Array(data.affectedRows);
          const pkField = this.model.rawAttributes[this.model.primaryKeyAttribute].field;

// *** THIS SEQUENTIAllY INCREMENTS THE ID *** //
          for (let i = 0; i < data.affectedRows; i++) {
            result[i] = { [pkField]: startId + i };
          }
          return [result, data.affectedRows];
        }

        return [data[this.getInsertIdField()], data.affectedRows];
      }
    }

    //... more code
```

This code describes the table to get the `auto_increment` value for the table that the above code is based on.

***`./sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js`***

```
  describeTableQuery(tableName, schema, schemaDelimiter) {
    const table = this.quoteTable(
      this.addSchema({
        tableName,
        _schema: schema,
        _schemaDelimiter: schemaDelimiter
      })
    );

    return `DESCRIBE ${table};`;
  }
```

The `describeTableQuery()` is called in the `describeTable()` method in:
***`/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-abstract.js`***

```
  async describeTable(tableName, options) {
//... code
    const sql = this.queryGenerator.describeTableQuery(tableName, schema, schemaDelimiter);
    options = { ...options, type: QueryTypes.DESCRIBE };

    try {
      const data = await this.sequelize.query(sql, options);
// ...more code
```

There is a bit more code in the MariaDB dialect classes that work around the ID not being returned directly from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this. I looked in the MySQL dialect and saw a similar version of the MariaDB code. Incrementing by one programmatically when an autoincrement PK is detected.

Comment: @sergiopereira oops, I mistakenly thought you were using MariaDB, but like you said they are pretty interchangeable for the most part.